# Python flask debug or run keep getting : Unable to find python module message

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, flask, module

i have simple flask server running in vscode , i enable to debug and run but i keep getting the message :

```
Unable to find python module.
```

on each step i do in the IDE

```
foo.foo-PC MINGW64 /c/dev/my/microservices_tests/python/b37 -- -m flask run --no-debugger --no-reload ^C
roservices_tests\\python\\broker-service\\app.py \\debugpy\\launcher 63493 -- c:\\dev\\my\\micr
meir.yanovich@MEIRYANO-PC MINGW64 /c/dev/my/microservices_tests/python/broker-service
$  cd c:\\dev\\my\\microservices_tests\\python\\broker-service ; /usr/bin/env c:\\msys64\\mingw64\\bin\\python.exe c:\\Users\\meir.yanovich\\.vscode\\extensions\\ms-python.python-2023.4.1\\pythonFiles\\lib\\python\\debugpy\\adapter/../..\\debugpy\\launcher 63741 -- -m flask run --no-debugger --no-reload
Unable to find python module.
Unable to find python module.
Unable to find python module.
Unable to find python module.
Unable to find python module.
Unable to find python module.
Unable to find python module.
 * Serving Flask app 'app.py'
 * Debug mode: on
WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment. Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000
Press CTRL+C to quit


python -m pip list
Package            Version
------------------ -------
click              8.1.3
colorama           0.4.6
distlib            0.3.3
Flask              2.2.3
Flask-Cors         3.0.10
importlib-metadata 6.0.0
itsdangerous       2.1.2
Jinja2             3.1.2
MarkupSafe         2.1.2
pip                22.0.4
PyYAML             6.0
ruamel.yaml        0.17.21
ruamel.yaml.clib   0.2.6
setuptools         59.8.0
six                1.16.0
Werkzeug           2.2.3
zipp               3.15.0


which python
/c/msys64/mingw64/bin/python

$ python --version
Python 3.9.10
```